# Positioning my submenus

Tags: html, css, submenu

Currently, when revealing my submenus they appear like this:

[image]

What I want is for it to appear to the right of the main menu, without changing the height of the main menu. Perhaps, something like this:

[image]

I cant seem to figure out the CSS in order to do this.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="sortmenu">
    <div id="sortmenu_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a>Song</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>Artist</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>Album</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>   
            <a>Genre</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>Release Date</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>Newest to Oldest</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Oldest to Newest</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>BPM</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>Slowest to Fastest</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Fastest to Slowest</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#sortmenu {
background-color: #222;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;
border: 5px solid DarkBlue;
}
#sortmenu_wrapper {
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}





#sortmenu ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
min-width: 200px;
}
#sortmenu ul > li {
display: block;
width: 200px;
}
#sortmenu ul li:hover {
background-color: #333;
}
#sortmenu ul li a{
color: #CCC;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#sortmenu ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}


.sortsubmenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid DarkBlue;
border-left: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
width: 200px;
left: 100%;
margin-top: -30px;
}
.sortsubmenu > li {
display: block;
position: relative;
}
.sortsubmenu li a:hover {
color: #699;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi now define your `#sortmenu ul > li`  `position: relative;` and `#sortmenu ul > li ul`  to this

```
position:absolute;
        right:0;
        top:-5px;
```

---

**As like thi**s

```
#sortmenu ul > li {
    position: relative;
}
#sortmenu ul > li ul{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:-5px;
}
```

==============Demo is

```css
#sortmenu {
background-color: #222;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;
border: 5px solid DarkBlue;
}
#sortmenu_wrapper {
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}





#sortmenu ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
min-width: 200px;
}
#sortmenu ul > li {
display: block;
width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#sortmenu ul > li ul{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:-5px;
}
#sortmenu ul li:hover {
background-color: #333;
}
#sortmenu ul li a{
color: #CCC;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#sortmenu ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}


.sortsubmenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid DarkBlue;
border-left: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
width: 200px;
left: 100%;
margin-top: -30px;
}
.sortsubmenu > li {
display: block;
position: relative;
}
.sortsubmenu li a:hover {
color: #699;
}
```

```html
<div id="sortmenu">
    <div id="sortmenu_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a>Song</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>Artist</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>Album</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>   
            <a>Genre</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Z to A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>Release Date</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>Newest to Oldest</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Oldest to Newest</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a>BPM</a>
                <ul class="sortsubmenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>Slowest to Fastest</a></li><li>
                    <a href='#'>Fastest to Slowest</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `position: absolute` being set on `.sortsubmenu` is overridden by the `position: relative` being set on `#sortmenu ul`.

To fix that and avoid further problems on the future, when you set your style inside `.sortsubmenu` maker sure you add `#sortmenu` so the styles set there will be a priority.

From :

```
.sortsubmenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 5px solid DarkBlue;
  border-left: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

To:

```
#sortmenu .sortsubmenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 5px solid DarkBlue;
  border-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  left: 100%;
  top: -5px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5suw6vg/1/)